# Successive over-relaxation not converging (when not done in-place)

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I'm trying to find the potential given some boundary conditions using the successive over-relaxation method.

I have 2 solutions:

-One iterates over all elements and applies the formula `field[y,x] = (1-alpha)*field[y,x] + (field[max(y-1,0),x] + field[min(y+1,field.shape[0]-1),x] + field[y,max(x-1,0)] + field[y,min(x+1,field.shape[1]-1)]) * alpha/4` in place. This is slow because it doesn't access memory in a nice way.

-The other one, I create 4 matrices shifted in the 4 directions by 1. I Apply the same formula by then adding the matrices up. This however doesn't take into account modifications done during the current iteration. This is significantly faster then the previous one.

With alpha = 1.9 the first algorithm converges while the second one doesn't. For alpha = 1.0 both converge but very slowly.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? And how can I fix the fast solution.

Full code:

```
#! python3

import numpy
import math
import time

def solve_laplace(boundary, mask, file = None, alpha = 1.0, threshold = 0.0001):
    """
    We are using the successive over-relaxation method. We iterate until our solution changes less than some threshold value.

    Vm+1(x,y,...) = alpha*( ((Vm(x-1,y,...) + Vm(x+1,y,...) + Vm(x,y-1,...) + Vm(x,y+1,...) + ...)/(2*nr dimensions) ) + (1-alpha)*Vm(x,y,...)
    """

    dim = boundary.ndim

    threshold = 0.0001
    field = numpy.zeros_like(boundary)
    numpy.copyto(field, boundary, casting = "safe", where = mask)
    last_diff = float("infinity")

    for iter_nr in range(10000):#max number of iterations
        prev = field.copy() #make a copy of the field at the start of the iteration (python always stores pointers unless you explicitly copy something)

        for d in range(dim): #can be scaled to arbitrary dimensions, using 2D for testing

            #these 2 blocks are hard to follow but they work, read the comments
            front = prev[tuple(0 if i==d else slice(None) for i in range(dim))] #select front face of cube/whatever
            front = front[tuple(numpy.newaxis if i==d else slice(None) for i in range(dim))] #prepare it for next step
            front = numpy.concatenate((front,prev),d) #add it the previous iteration's result
            front = front[tuple(slice(-1) if i==d else slice(None) for i in range(dim))] #remove the back side of the previous iteration's result
            #we now have the volume shifted right by 1 pixel, x now corresponds to the x-1 term

            back = prev[tuple(-1 if i==d else slice(None) for i in range(dim))] #select back face of cube/whatever
            back = back[tuple(numpy.newaxis if i==d else slice(None) for i in range(dim))] #prepare it for next step
            back = numpy.concatenate((prev,back),d) #add it the previous iteration's result
            back = back[tuple(slice(1,None) if i==d else slice(None) for i in range(dim))] #remove the front side of the previous iteration's result
            #we now have the volume shifted left by 1 pixel, x now corresponds to the x+1 term

            field += (front + back) * alpha/(2*dim) #this part of the formula: alpha*( ((Vm(x-1,y,...) + Vm(x+1,y,...) + Vm(x,y-1,...) + Vm(x,y+1,...))/(2*nr dimensions)
            #numpy.copyto(field, boundary, casting = "safe", where = mask)

        field -= alpha*prev #this part of the formula: (1-alpha)*Vm(x,y,...)
        #reset values at boundaries
        numpy.copyto(field, boundary, casting = "safe", where = mask) 

        #check if the difference is less than threshold
        average = math.sqrt(numpy.average(field**2)) #sqrt of average of squares, just so i get a positive number
        diff = math.sqrt(numpy.average((field-prev)**2)) #standard deviation

        if last_diff < diff/average:
            print("Solution is diverging.")
            break

        if diff/average < threshold:
            print("Found solution after", iter_nr,"iteratiorn.")
            break

        last_diff = diff/average

    if file is not None:
        numpy.save(file,field)
    return field



def solve_laplace_slow_2D(boundary, mask, file = None, alpha = 1.9,threshold = 0.0001):
    """
    We are using the successive over-relaxation method. We iterate until our solution changes less than some threshold value.

    Vm+1(x,y,...) = alpha*( ((Vm(x-1,y,...) + Vm(x+1,y,...) + Vm(x,y-1,...) + Vm(x,y+1,...) + ...)/(2*nr dimensions) ) + (1-alpha)*Vm(x,y,...)
    """

    assert boundary.ndim == 2

    field = numpy.zeros_like(boundary)
    numpy.copyto(field, boundary, casting = "safe", where = mask) 
    last_diff = float("infinity")
    start_time = time.time()

    for iter_nr in range(10000):#max number of iterations
        prev = field.copy()
        for y in range(field.shape[0]):
            for x in range(field.shape[1]):
                if not mask[y,x]:
                    field[y,x] = (1-alpha)*field[y,x] + (field[max(y-1,0),x] + field[min(y+1,field.shape[0]-1),x] + field[y,max(x-1,0)] + field[y,min(x+1,field.shape[1]-1)]) * alpha/4

        #check if the difference is less than threshold
        average = math.sqrt(numpy.average(field**2)) #sqrt of average of squares, just so i get a positive number
        diff = math.sqrt(numpy.average((field-prev)**2)) #standard deviation

        if last_diff < diff/average:
            print("Solution is diverging.")
            break

        if diff/average < threshold:
            print("Found solution after the", iter_nr,"iteratiorn.")
            break

        if time.time() - start_time > 3600:
            print("Completed in an hour time at iteration:", iter_nr)
            break

        last_diff = diff/average

        #print(time.time() - start_time, iter_nr, last_diff)

    if file is not None:
        numpy.save(file,field)
    return field

def test():
    boundary = numpy.zeros((51,51))
    boundary[25,25] = 1
    for i in range(51):
        boundary[0,i] = -1
        boundary[50,i] = -1
        boundary[i,0] = -1
        boundary[i,50] = -1
    mask = (boundary != 0)

    print("Trying fast method:")
    solve_laplace(boundary,mask,alpha = 1.5) #diverges
    print("Trying slow method:")
    solve_laplace_slow_2D(boundary,mask,alpha = 1.5) #converges but is very slow
```

Comment: Maybe http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ would better place to ask?

Comment: I've posted there as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky stuff... If you can define your whole operation in a single ufunc like call, **and** the ufunc is run without buffering, you may be able to do this type of iterative calculations very fast. In your case, the inside of your array could be processed in a single shot as follows:

```
>>> a = np.arange(25, dtype=np.double).reshape(5, 5)
>>> from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
>>> rows, cols = a.shape
>>> a_view = as_strided(a, shape=(rows-3+1, cols-3+1, 3, 3) ,strides=a.strides*2)
>>> alpha = 2
>>> mask = [[0, alpha/4, 0], [alpha/4, 1-alpha, alpha/4], [0, alpha/4, 0]]
```

If we process the inside of the array without updating, we would get:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijkl,kl->ij', a_view, mask)
array([[  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [ 11.,  12.,  13.],
       [ 16.,  17.,  18.]])
```

But if we tell np.einsum to store the result in the same array, then see what happens:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijkl,kl->ij', a_view, mask, out=a[1:-1, 1:-1])
array([[  3.       ,   2.25     ,   5.625    ],
       [  5.5625   ,   4.1875   ,   9.09375  ],
       [ 19.046875 ,  17.546875 ,  24.2734375]])
>>> a
array([[  0.       ,   1.       ,   2.       ,   3.       ,   4.       ],
       [  5.       ,   3.       ,   2.25     ,   5.625    ,   9.       ],
       [ 10.       ,   5.5625   ,   4.1875   ,   9.09375  ,  14.       ],
       [ 15.       ,  19.046875 ,  17.546875 ,  24.2734375,  19.       ],
       [ 20.       ,  21.       ,  22.       ,  23.       ,  24.       ]])
```

You would then need to process the borders separately, but for large arrays the border is a negligible part of the total amount of calculations. And you will not get the exact same update pattern as in your original solution, unless you process it one row at a time, and trade speed for consistency. But it will boost performance by a lot. Your main concern should be that this is depending on implementation details, and there is no guarantee that in a future version of numpy the buffering of np.einsum will change and will ruin your code. But if your array is well behaved (properly aligned and in native byte order), as will be unless you do weird things when creating it, there is a good chance that it will work.